# Formatting of numbers: Get rid of thousand separators (comma, quote, etc)

Tags: numbers, format, separator, squirrel-sql

I use version 3.4.0 of SQuirreL SQL client, and whenever I execute a request that returns numbers (IDs for example), the result numbers are formatted with commas, i.e. `123,456,789` instead of plain `123456789`. How can I change this formatting, so that there are no more commas?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Sure can do:

- Open the "File" menu
- Select "Global preferences"
- Select the "Data Type Controls" tab
- Scroll all the way down
- The last section deals with "FLOAT, REAL, DOUBLE, NUMERIC, DECIMAL (SQL types 6, 7, 8, 2, 3)". There, select the "default format" option. See also this screenshot:

[image: SquirrelSQL Data Type Controls]