# PostgreSQL how to read csv file with decimal comma?

Tags: postgresql, csv, decimal-point

I try to read a csv file containing real numbers with a comma as separator. I try to read this file with \copy in psql:

\copy table FROM 'filename.csv' DELIMITER ';' CSV HEADER;

psql does not recognize the comma as decimal point.

psql:filename.sql:44: ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type real: "9669,84"
CONTEXT:  COPY filename, line 2, column col-3: "9669,84"

I did some googling but could not find any answer other than "change the decimal comma into a decimal point". I tried SET DECIMALSEPARATORCOMMA=ON;  but that did not work. I also experimented with some encoding but I couldn't find whether encoding governs the decimal point (I got the impression it didn't).

Is there really no solution other than changing the input data?

Answer (score 2):

`COPY` to a table where you insert the number into a varchar field. Then do something like in `psql`:

```
--Temporarily change numeric formatting to one that uses ',' as
--decimal separator.
set lc_numeric = "de_DE.UTF-8";
--Below is just an example. In your case the select would be part of 
--insert into the target table. Also the first part of to_number
--would be the field from your staging table.
select to_number('9669,84', '99999D999');
9669.84
```

You might need to change the format string to match all the numbers. For more information on what is available see [Data formatting](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html) Table 9.28. Template Patterns for Numeric Formatting.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the usage of quotes indicate this is a string.

So, either:

- the data type of the db column needs to be updated to match
- the input data needs to not indicate it is a string (e.g., the SQuirrel client automatically formats the floats and that causes this issue - that can be turned off when exporting data as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33366852/8285811))

Comment: AFAIK CSV does not indicate data types associated with its columns.

Comment: @amphetamachine The db does. That's what I'm talking about.