# How to import CSV files into postgresql with decimal values separted with comma instead of point?

Tags: postgresql, csv, type-conversion, char, numeric

In my zipped csv file is a column with numeric values separeted by comma. Is it possible to import the comma separted numeric value in postgresql as numeric on the file without update and type changing?

```
copy  
    "t_test" ("textColumn","numericColumnAsText") 
FROM PROGRAM 
    'c:\unixutils\unzip -p C:\tmp\csv_dummy.zip' 
WITH 
    (FORMAT csv, DELIMITER ';',  NULL 'NULL',  header);

update "t_test"  set "numericColumnAsText" = to_number("numericColumnAsText", '99999D999');

alter table "t_test"  alter column "numericColumnAsText" TYPE numeric  USING ("numericColumn"::numeric) ;
```

I think it can be easier...

Comment: It is not: `select '10,000'::numeric; ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type numeric: "10,000"`. There is this: `select to_number('10,000', '99G999'); 10000` per [Formatting functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html). Though that would mean importing to text field and then converting.

Comment: See this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69417495/postgresql-how-to-read-csv-file-with-decimal-comma

Comment: 1) How are trying to import the CSV, via Postgres `\copy` or `COPY` or through some other method? 2) What client or programming language are you working with?

Comment: via COPY and postgresql

Comment: Then you will need to `COPY` to a staging table and then do the `text` --> `numeric` transformation on the INSERT/UPDATE to the final table.